# How to give action to different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am very new to android so please excuse me if my question is an obvious one. I have to split the screen in 2 parts and give action to each of the fragments. One part will plot the data and the other part will display the data. I have used fragments to split the screen but I want to know how to give the action to each of the fragments so that it starts together.

I don't want to initiate any fragment with a click of button or else. I want that as soon as the app starts, then both the fragments starts to display their respective plots and data.

Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

EDIT

I have attached the codes
PlotFragment.java (the file which I want to run in one of the fragment as the app is launched)

```
package com.tempsensor;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlotFragment extends FragmentActivity {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Plot Comes Here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java (the java file which contains the Activity within which I have created the two fragments)

```
package com.tempsensor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button buttonexit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        buttonexit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonexit.setOnClickListener(this);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.plot_fragment, new PlotFragment()).commit();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.data_fragment, new DataFragment()).commit();

    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0==buttonexit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }       
}
```

Where am I making a mistake, the desired result is that when the app launches these two fragments should start their task automatically, here I am just trying to print a text using Toast.

Comment: are you using Fragment Transactions (to add the fragments)? Or the fragments are embedded in the layout?

Comment: @Wakim The fragments are embedded in the layout.

Comment: Maybe you can retrieve the fragments using their's `tags` and set the `Fragment` data on `onCreate` (after `setContentView`) on the `Activity`. It doesn't work?

Comment: @Wakim I did the same thing, but I guess I am making some mistake in doing it successfully.

Comment: when you said "embedded" i think they are defined in the `Activity` layout, using `<fragment ... />`. I'll post an answer, but is very similar with what you doing.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the app to open and show both fragments with all their info already loaded, a plot on one and data in the other?

In the activity that is launched, you are creating a fragment and committing a transaction that adds it to a container, correct?  All you should have to do do the same for the other fragment: create it and commit a transaction adding it to the other container.

Here's some simple code demonstrating what I mean:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.plot_container, new PlotFragment()).commit();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.data_container, new DataFragment()).commit();

}
```

Comment: yes you have understood my question correctly, I have included my codes in the edit. Could you please point out the correct method to achieve my aim please.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can create method in second fragment. This method will return needed data.
For example: you must to get instanse of fragment in current activity and call this method like this:

```
for (Fragment f : getActivity().getFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                            if (f instanceof SecondFragment) {
                                int data = ((SecondFragment) f).returnData();
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i suggest you to change the way you add the fragments to the layout, something like this:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        buttonexit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonexit.setOnClickListener(this);

        PlotFragment plotFrag = new PlotFragment();
        DataFragment dataFrag = new DataFragment();

        addData(plotFrag);
        addData(dataFrag);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.plot_fragment, plotFrag).commit();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.data_fragment, dataFrag).commit();
    }

    protected void addData(DataFragment dataFrag) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        // Load data to args variable

        dataFrag.setArguments(args);
    }

    protected void addData(PlotFragment plotFrag) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        // Load plot data to args variable

        plotFrag.setArguments(args);
    }
}
```

In the `Fragments` classes:

```
public class DataFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState){

        Bundle args = getArguments() == null ? savedInstanceState : getArguments();

        // Use args to setup Fragment content

        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Comes Here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
}

public class PlotFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState){

        Bundle args = getArguments() == null ? savedInstanceState : getArguments();

        // Use args to setup Fragment content

        Toast.makeText(this, "Plot Comes Here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
}
```